# Cannot get puts to display read()

Tags: ruby

Below is my code which seems to run fine and writes to the file as is intended.  However, I just can't get line 45, puts target.read(), to display the contents of target at all.  Please help.  Oh, and any other critique or suggestions about other parts of my code would be greatly appreciated as well.

```
filename = ARGV.first
script = $0

puts "We're going to erase #{filename}."
puts "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C."
puts "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

print ">>"
STDIN.gets

puts "Opening the file...."
target = File.open(filename, 'w')

puts "Truncating the file."
target.truncate(target.size)

puts "Now, I'm going to ask for you three lines."

print "line 1: "; line1 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line 2: "; line2 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line 3: "; line3 = STDIN.gets.chomp()

puts "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
puts "Do you want to continue and perform the same"
puts "task with one line of target.write() methods?"
puts "Give me a 'yes' or a 'no'."
print ">>"
answer = STDIN.gets.chomp()
puts "=============================="
if answer == "yes"
target.write("#{line1}\n#{line2}\n#{line3}\n")
end

puts "This is the content of #{filename}:\n"
target = File.open(filename)
# Cannot figure out why the program is not displaying the contents
# of the target file when it's run.
puts target.read()
puts "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open `target` for reading as such:

```
target = File.open(filename, 'r')
```

According to the docs, [`read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read) takes an integer argument for the number of bytes to read.  Instead of this I suggest using an iterative approach and printing the lines one by one.  You also will not have to open the file before, but I thought I would show you the 'r' argument in open anyways.

This is what I would do:

```
IO.foreach(filename) do |line|
  puts line
end
```

This method closes the file after the block is done so no need to explicitly call close.  Before this read though, make sure to close the file after you have written to it.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'll be sure to read up on read() method more for a better understanding.  I'll give your block of code a try.  Thanks, again.

Comment: @RipRocK If you have questions let me know. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in 'w+' [mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html):

```
target = File.open(filename,'w+')
```

That way it opens the file read-write, truncating existing file to zero length
or creating a new file for reading and writing. So the explicit truncating later in your code is not needed.

When you are done writing, the file cursor is at the end of the text. The cursor should be put back on the first byte before you start reading:

```
target.rewind
```

Comment: Great, great.  I'll play around with your snippets and see what kind of results I get.  Thank you.

Comment: @RipRocK Once you get something working consider posting it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) for critique and suggestions.